# How to "pause" a script until asyncio is closed

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have a function that calls a class, after the class has been initilized it will continue down the function, as it should. However i want to pause after the class has been initilized until the asyncio is closed from inside the class.

Something like this:

```
from PyHook3 import HookManager
import asyncio


class Keystroke_Watcher(object):
    def __init__(self, event_loop):
        self.event_loop = event_loop

        self.hm = HookManager()
        self.hm.KeyDown = self.on_keyboard_event
        self.hm.HookKeyboard()


    def on_keyboard_event(self, event):
        if event.KeyID == 65:  # A
            self.shutdown()
        return True

    def shutdown(self):
        self.hm.UnhookKeyboard()
        self.event_loop.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    watcher = Keystroke_Watcher(loop)
    loop.run_forever()
    print("Done!")
```

The idea is the "main" code shouldn't continue until after the "A" key has been pressed. However with this current code it will freeze all keyboard actions, and it won't stop even after A is pressed.

Am I using the wrong asyncio loop?

Doesn't it work well with classes?

What would be the best solution to this problem? (doesn't necessarily to involve asyncio in solution)

Note: I know that Qt has something that does exactly this, however i don't feel like including the entire qt library. QEventLoop().exec() to start it and QEventLoop().exit() to end it.

Comment: I don't feel `asyncio` does anything here. Just pausing a python file until some key is pressed is trivial (without PyHook), so I feel that you're actually trying to do something more complex, but made an abstraction for this question that misses the point.

Comment: The reason why it doesn't do anything is because it freezes everything. Now in a real world application it would obviously do more then just register one button, however the concept remains. For example I want the application to freeze until the user presses A then proceed with the code. Lets say that everytime a user presses A a new line of text will appear or something, however the problem that i run into without using asyncio or anything else for that matter is that when the class has been initlized it will continue running the main loop.

Comment: I would remove all asyncio stuff here. It is not doing anything useful. I suspect ``PyHook3`` does not even support asyncio, and will not pass control to the asyncio event loop while waiting on keystrokes. In fact -
looking at [the example](https://github.com/gggfreak2003/PyHook3/blob/master/example.py), it appears ``PyHook3`` requires the event loop from ``pythoncom`` -- ``pythoncom.PumpMessages()``. So the easiest solution would be to remove the asyncio. Which turns the question into "how do I use PyHook3?" which is something I cannot answer except to point you to the example code.